# define a series of matrices variables not using cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, cell

Here is my code:

```
A = zeros(10,10,10);
for i = 1:10
C{i} = A(:,:,i);
end
```

This is just a simple example and my question is: Is there any other way, NOT using a cell (C{i} in the code) to represent a series of 2D matrices variables (A(:,:,i) in the code) from a 3D matrix (A). Anyway I believe you will need some variable name like 'i'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `A(:,:,i)`? What are you trying to achieve that addressing a 3d array won't give you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
A = zeros(10,10,10);
for i = 1:10
    eval(sprintf('A%d = A(:,:,%d)',i,i));
end
```

In this way you get 10 matrices whose names are A1, A2, ..., Ai,...

Anyway I suggest not using this method. It is more readable the one with cell arrays.